# Node.js spawn child process and get terminal output to log realtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, electron, child-process

I want to exec a program called 'Game.exe' with Node.js child_process, the program will print a number every second to terminal, but it will crash randomly.

I want to log the output to a file called 'Back.log', but with the code I currently write, the log file will never be created. What`s the problem?

```
var game = child_process.spawn('Game.exe')
game.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    fs.appendFile('Back.log', data.toString(), function (err) { })
})
game.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    fs.appendFile('Back.log', data.toString(), function (err) { })
})
game.on('close', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    fs.appendFile('Back.log', data.toString(), function (err) { })
})
```

This code is positioned in electron main process, and is 3000ms delay by using `setTimeout(startScript, 3000)`

Comment: does `fs.appendFile('Back.log', 'test', console.log);` work?

Comment: @RolandStarke No, and there is no log on terminal.

Comment: "it will crash randomly" Does it mean your electron app was crashed?

Comment: @HaiPham No, in fact, my electron app is just alright but the program I executed will crash randomly

Comment: @Miswanting please use electron-log instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log